# order of element in symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

let $n=p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_k$ ($p_k$ is kth prime number) then $\prod_{i=1}^k p_i$ is maximum order in $S_n$.

I think it is easy but I am trying to prove it , but I have not any idea how to deal with it.
any suggestions ?

thanks

Comment: @martin sleziak :thanks martin

Comment: @jonas meyer the part 1 is not hard I can construct element with order \prod_{i=1}^k p_i but i can't show the part 2

Comment: yes but i cant show this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It isn't true in general.  I found a reference to a counterexample with Google's help (specifically mentioned in [this article](http://digitallibrary.sissa.it/bitstream/handle/1963/3520/12s1_28.pdf?sequence=2), page 9 of the pdf file, page 359 of the publication).  Namely, when $k=9$, so that$$n=100=2+3+5+7+11+13+17+19+23,$$ note that $$2^4+3^2+5+7+11+13+17+19=97<100,$$ so $S_{100}$ has an element of order $$2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19=232,792,560,$$ which is greater than $$2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23=223,092,870.$$

Comment: (I am not sure if the link is meant to persist, so I am posting a reference to the said article.) David Gomez-Ullate and Matteo Sommacal, *Periods of the Goldﬁsh Many-Body Problem* (*Journal of Nonlinear Mathematical Physics*).