# Finding the inverse of an element of $S_n$ and it's order

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I have two questions,

1) What are the ways to find the inverse of an element of $S_n$?

2) What are the ways to find the order of an element of $S_n$?

Comment: Regarding 2) see the discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251333/orders-of-a-symmetric-group?rq=1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102343/order-of-element-in-symmetric-group), or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group). Regarding 1), try first the tranpositions $(i,j)$.

Comment: On this site, if you have two questions, ask *two* questions. Please do not bundle them. Link them when they're related.

Answer (score 2):

If you write the elements of $S_n$ as matrices as follows:
$$
\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &2 &3& 4 \\ 3& 4& 1 &2
\end{pmatrix},
$$

(wher of course $\sigma(1)=3, \sigma(2)=4$, and so on), then you can find the inverse just by turning the matrix upside down:
$$
\sigma^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 &4 &1& 2 \\ 1& 2& 3&4
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Of course the ordering is different, but you can still read off that ,for example $\sigma^{-1}(3)=1, \sigma^{-1}(4)=2$, and so on.

In conclusion, the answer depends upon what you mean by "finding the inverse".

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma \in S_{n}$, then $\sigma = \tau_{1} \tau_{2} \ldots \tau_{k}$ where $\tau_{i}$ is a transposition for each $i= 1,2 \ldots k$.
Then $\sigma^{-1} =  \tau_{k} \tau_{k-1} \ldots \tau_{2} \tau_{1}$.
There are many ways to find the order of an arbitrary element of $S_{n}$, it's sometimes useful to write $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles. Say $\sigma = \mu_{1} \mu_{2} \ldots \mu_{j}$. As disjoint cycles commute, if $\mu_{i} $ has length $l_{i}$, then the order of $\sigma$ is the least common multiple of the $l_{i}$'s.